# not sure cut -f mean in bash

Tags: bash

```
STATUS='yes'
FOO='pretty'
BAR='purple'
for var in STATUS FOO BAR; do
#    declare -p $var | cut -d ' ' -f 3- >> variable.file
        declare -p $var >> variable.file
done
```

returns

```
declare -- STATUS="yes"
declare -- FOO="pretty"
declare -- BAR="purple"
```

1. not sure `-f` options means?   when I not attach `-f` it says `you must specify a list of bytes, characters or fields?  The [manual](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/declareh.html) says

> `-f` restrict action or display to function names and definitions

2. `cut -d ' '` make it into 3 fields. `declare`,  `--`, `STATUS="yes"`?
3. If 2 is correct, then `3-` will get the last field, which contains
   STATUS="yes"
   FOO="pretty"
   BAR="purple"

Overall, I am not sure point1, since the result match with point2,point3, but I also want to confirm my point2, point3 interpretation is correct.

Comment: That man page you tag is for the Bash built-in command `declare`. It has nothing to do with the external command `cut`.

Comment: `cut -f 3-` takes all fields from the third one to the last. `cut` has no understanding of the syntax of the strings it gets. If the value of the variable contains spaces like `FOO="I like Jam"` than that is fields 3, 4, and 5 because of the spaces included within the quotes.

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question is? Are you asking what `cut -d ' ' -f 3-` means? Or are you trying to get a specific output and save it into `variable.file`? Is this not the output you want? What are you expecting?

Comment: @terdon Now I understand `-f` mean.  Sometimes. I also want to confirm my point2, point3 interpretation is correct. based on @Paul_Pedant explanation, seems like my interpretation is correct.

Comment: To get only the 3rd field, you would use `cut -d ' ' -f 3`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @terdon correct. But the werid part is `declare` is just literal declare., so using `-p` to pull all the variable values and attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cut`, `-f` specifies which field to extract. "fields" are separated by the delimiter,  a <kbd>Space</kbd> character, in your case. Each <kbd>Space</kbd> delimits a field, so, if your data has multiple <kbd>Space</kbd> characters (check with `od -bc your.file`), it has multiple "fields", according to `cut`.
Other tools, e.g. `awk '{print $3} your.file` have different ideas of "fields".
BTW, your `man` page quote is not from `man cut`. Switches, like `-f`, have no global meaning - they mean different things to different programs.

Comment: Awk would have exactly the same idea of fields as `cut` here. You are just telling `awk` to print only the 3rd field, while the OP is telling cut to print from the 3rd until the end. But the fields will be the same for both programs in this case.

Comment: @terdon `awk`'s default field separator treats multiple separator characters (whitespace) the same as just **one** separator character.  `cut` does not and has no option to do so.  e.g. see the difference between: `echo "1 2   3 4 5" | cut -d' ' -f 3`, `echo "1 2   3 4 5" | awk '{print $3}'`, `echo "1 2   3 4 5" | awk -F' ' '{print $3}'`,  and `echo "1 2   3 4 5" | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $3}'` (only the last awk command works like cut).  OTOH, cut's `-f` option can easily & conveniently output multiple fields at once, whereas you'd have to DIY that in awk (e.g. with a for loop).

Comment: @cas all this is true but not relevant here since we have a specific string with single spaces, so `awk` and `cut -d ' '` would have exactly the same idea of what a field is, unlike what this answer suggests.

Comment: I pointed it out because a novice is unlikely to realise the significance of your "here" qualifier - there's a good chance they won't even notice it. awk and cut do not have "exactly the same idea of fields". In some cases, with specific input data and formatting, that doesn't matter on a practical level. In others, it does. But it always matters on a conceptual level - awk and cut have very different concepts of what a field is, or can be. Not understanding that can lead to buggy or broken code due to choosing the wrong tool for the job (or not taking those differences into account).